# Monitoring updates for Ubuntu VPS

Tags: updates

I am running a VPS. Once in a while I will see critical updates that have been released, so I go ahead and apply in my environment as needed. I look at this being a reactive approach and not proactive. How do you guys monitor patches/updates for your Ubuntu environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of tools that notify you about impending package updates. I personally use `apticron`. That tool checks once a day whether there are pending updates and, if there are, sends a notification mail. apticron needs an MTA (for example Postfix) installed to send the mail. The mails are sent to `root`, so you need to redirect `root`'s mail, for example with an alias in `/etc/aliases`.

Other similar tools are `cron-apt` and the succinctly named `painintheapt`. According to its description, `painintheapt` can send notifications over SMTP or XMPP/Jabber, so you don't need to have an MTA installed.

Comment: your solution worked great and I am getting mails to remind me daily of updates outstanding. the only thing is i have been avoiding them which is probably not the best idea but there are total of 90 updates outstanding. how would you go about updating? run backup and apt-get update the whole lot?

Comment: @StephanGriesel If you didn't stray too far from Ubuntus defaults on structures, configurations and so on, it shouldn't be too much of a problem just to install the updates. You might need to re-adjust something here or there.  In any case, it's a good idea not to let a lot of pending updates accumulate, especially security related updates. You also should read through the change logs to see whether you need any extra adjustments for your specific situation.

Comment: @StefanGriesel In general, you might want to take into account how the server is used and what that means for the updates. For example, it might be wise to apply the updates after office hours. Or you might want to inform the people using the server that there will be a short downtime while you apply the updates and make any neccessary changes. Also, there's a new API for `apt` since apt 1.0. You might want to read up on `apt update`, `apt full-upgrade`, `apt list` etc. Same goes for the differences between `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get dist-upgrade`etc.

Comment: no didnt change too much, only thing i did was disable root account, set up new named root account and installed plesk. so you think it is safe running these updates? just don't want to cause downtime for my client's websites running on this server.

Comment: Judging from what you said it shouldn't be a problem. But I'd plan for at least *some* downtime. If all works well, the server shouldn't be offline for more than a few seconds. But if any problems occur, better to have some buffer to work them out. I'd suggest the routine approach: Determine a time window, say 30 or 60 minutes, where a downtime would be tolerable (probably after office hours or late at night). Announce that maintenance window to your customers early enough in advance, and do the upgrades in that time window.